# Excel oleobject cannot delete

Tags: vba, excel

I put date picker to my sheet and got a lot of problem

1. I cant select or delete thoose dtpickers nor manualy nor from VBA as this code

> ```
> Dim obj As OLEObject
> For Each obj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
>         obj.Delete
>     End If
> Next
> ```

Return an error

> application defined or object-defined error

2. I using Office 2013 32bit, other computers with Office 2010 32bit, Office 2007 32bit, Office 2013 32bit. I cant run compiled workbook on others computers, as i get in refences missing

> microsoft windows common controls 2 6.0 sp6

Which also cannot be removed as is in use. I cannot uncheck it.

3. Most of my project functions and parameters such (Ucase, Mid, Left, wdAlignParagraphLeft) start getting error as undefined. Also all undeclared variables got the same error. Solving only by writing it with prefix VBA.Ucase, VBA.Mid and etc. and declaring all variables.
4. Also in developer tab insert control button not active anymore in all computers also in my computer too.

So question is? how to delete thoose dtpickers object and fix my project?
How to know what depend to `microsoft windows common controls 2 6.0 sp6` library?

Comment: It seems you're referencing a library that's not on your users' computer - it will fail and keep failing until the users' computers have that library installed.

Comment: I know it, but why i cant delete datepicker in own computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove protection from your sheet and then select and delete objects, after that go to VBA editor and uncheck this library from references and restart your Excel application.